# How to deal with dependencies using log4j 1.x, when project uses log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

My project is using log4j2, and everything looks fine until running an application that uses a third party library that uses log4j 1.x. When our application starts, we get an annoying stack trace involving a ClassNotFoundException on org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender. I noticed that one of our dependencies has a log4j.properties inside its jar referencing org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender, so I'm guessing that's the reason for the stack trace. A couple other dependencies causing this error include most anything using JBoss logging classes, like embedded glassfish and the eclipse persistence packages.

I tried adding log4j-1.2.bridge api jar to the classpath and it had no effect.

It seems a little ridiculous to include both the jars for log4j2 and log4j1.x in our application classpath. Is there any other alternative or fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links provided answers for me:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-172
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBLOGGING-95

It looks like we are using an out-dated version of JBoss logging that doesn't support log4j2. However, I'm still not sure what to do for the one dependency that includes a log4j.properties.

[edit] It turns out adding log4j-jcl-2.0 jar worked for that dependency.

Comment: I am running into same problem. simplejavamail in my app uses log4j 1.2 and hence I am looking for a solution that does not involve using two different versions of log4j. Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: You need to add the log4j2 "1.2.x api bridge jar" to your project.